# Flask app on Cloud Run: Successful GCS upload but no response back causing API to keep running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've developed a flask app which takes video as a input and detect the images from the video and stores the results in a csv file, which is then uploaded to a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket. Locally, when I run the Flask app, I receive the expected response, and the CSV file is successfully stored in the GCS bucket (This process takes nearly 15 to 20 minutes for 2 videos). However, after deploying the Flask app using a Docker image on Google Cloud Run, I'm facing an issue where the results are uploaded to the GCS bucket, but I'm not receiving a response from the API.I'm not able to figure out that whether the problem is with gunicorn or cloud run.

Cloud run settings:

- **Resources** Memory-8GiB, CPU-2
- **Requests**  Request timeout-3600,Maximum concurrent requests per instance-80
- **Execution environment** Default
- **CPU allocation and pricing** CPU is only allocated during request processing
- **Auto-scaling** Minimum number of instances-1,Maximum number of instances-100

The error as follows
[Logs in Cloud Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qifjy.png)

I removed Gunicorn from my Docker image, and the API started responding as expected.However,after one or two requests,again the same condition repeated where the API keeps running without giving me the response back.

*This is the first time I'm posting on stack overflow so apologise if have not added any needed information, so let me know if anything is needed.*

Comment: Have you tried successfully running your application as a docker container locally? also share complete error logs as text instead of image.

Comment: The HTTP max keep alive is 30 minutes. So the connection can be lost but the process continue and finish on Cloud Run. Check your logs. In addition 2 CPU is very low. How many CPU do you have on your computer? personally 16 @4.1Ghz. It's a huge difference with Cloud Run! 2 CPU @ 3.4Ghz https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms